# Watir with Firefox 48 - How do I use a custom profile?

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I can't seem to find anything about this, and I'm starting to get upset, because this code used to work:
`browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => "Anna"`

However, now that code, while it will launch firefox successfully if I use `:marionette => true`, if I use `:profile => "Anna"` or even if I do this:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox({:profile => profile,:marionette=> true})
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :desired_capabilities => caps
```

Watir will still launch firefox and work properly, but it is still using its own profile. I have custom x509 certificates I need to use in that profile (and the site is throwing "This site is not secure" screens at me because it's still in development), so how can I use it? I know there's a way to do it, but I've been Googling for an hour now and have yet to find it. Removing `:marionette => true` will let the profile load properly, but since Firefox 48 doesn't support the old Firefox driver, I can't make it work.

Comment: I think we're out of luck presently: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1103196 ; I'm surprised mozilla didn't wait until old driver is unsupported to iron out the new one :/